# Startup Failure for Neo4j on OSX 10.7.5 re: log4j.properties

Tags: java, macos, log4j, neo4j

Can't get any flavour of Neo4j (1.7.2, 1.8.2, 1.9.RC2) running on my MacBook due to issues with not finding "file:conf/log4j.properties" and it looks like even with `jakarta-log4j` installed from ports am bumping up against not being able to play… is it missing a .jar in the install? Any ideas? I can find other `log4j.properties` relating to other apps.

Already checked questions:
[Starting neo4j on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726754/starting-neo4j-on-mac) ,
[log4j can't initialize with my log4j.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945694/log4j-cant-initialize-with-my-log4j-properties)

Neo4j RC 1.9.2 version(Java 1.7 is actually installed but this is not the primary issue):

```
laptop:bin doduibhi$ ./neo4j start
WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please     use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [4223]... waiting for server to be ready.............. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.

<from_logdir> less neo4j.0.0.log
Jun 1, 2013 2:41:03 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
WARNING: WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime.      Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.

    6/1/13 2:41:03 PM org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper WARNING: WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:conf/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:459)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:243)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:177)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:conf/log4j.properties].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(ConfigurationUtils.java:447)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:177)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
```

Neo4j Community 1.8.2 version:

```
laptop:bin doduibhi$ ./neo4j info
Neo4j Server is not running
Using Java version: CurrentJDK
NEO4J_HOME:        /Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2
NEO4J_SERVER_PORT: 7474
NEO4J_INSTANCE:    /Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2
JAVA_HOME:         /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
JAVA_OPTS:         -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
CLASSPATH:         /Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/lucene-core-3.5.0.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-cypher-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-graph-algo-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-graph-matching-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-jmx-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-kernel-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-lucene-index-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-shell-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/neo4j-udc-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/scala-library-2.9.1-1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/lib/server-api-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/asm-analysis-3.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/asm-commons-3.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/asm-tree-3.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/asm-util-3.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/blueprints-core-1.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/blueprints-neo4j-graph-1.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/gremlin-groovy-1.5.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/gremlin-java-1.5.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/groovy-1.8.5.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.7.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.7.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/janino-2.5.10.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jansi-1.5.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jersey-multipart-1.9.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jettison-1.3.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jetty-6.1.25.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/logback-access-0.9.30.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/logback-classic-0.9.30.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/logback-core-0.9.30.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/mimepull-1.6.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/neo4j-cypher-plugin-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/neo4j-gremlin-plugin-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.2-static-web.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/pipes-1.0.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/rrd4j-2.0.7.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/conf/

laptop:bin doduibhi$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

laptop:bin doduibhi$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_21

laptop:bin doduibhi$ ./neo4j start
Starting Neo4j Server...log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:conf/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:459)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:243)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.server.storemigration.PreStartupStoreUpgrader.getConfigurator(PreStartupStoreUpgrader.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.server.storemigration.PreStartupStoreUpgrader.run(PreStartupStoreUpgrader.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.server.storemigration.PreStartupStoreUpgrader.main(PreStartupStoreUpgrader.java:57)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:conf/log4j.properties].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(ConfigurationUtils.java:447)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:142)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.server.storemigration.PreStartupStoreUpgrader.getConfigurator(PreStartupStoreUpgrader.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.server.storemigration.PreStartupStoreUpgrader.run(PreStartupStoreUpgrader.java:78)
    at org.neo4j.server.storemigration.PreStartupStoreUpgrader.main(PreStartupStoreUpgrader.java:57)


laptop:bin doduibhi$ uname -a
Darwin laptop.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

laptop:bin doduibhi$ pwd
/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/bin
```

Should log4j not be in here below somewhere as a lib?

```
laptop:lib doduibhi$ pwd
/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/system/lib

laptop:lib doduibhi$ ls -al | grep log
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 doduibhi  staff    60686 26 Oct  2011 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 doduibhi  staff    92824 20 Apr  2012 logback-access-0.9.30.jar
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 doduibhi  staff   246428 20 Apr  2012 logback-classic-0.9.30.jar
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 doduibhi  staff   323588 20 Apr  2012 logback-core-0.9.30.jar

laptop:conf doduibhi$ pwd
/Volumes/dat1/install/neo4j-community-1.8.2/conf

laptop:conf doduibhi$ ls -al
total 64
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 doduibhi  staff   340 18 May 18:40 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 doduibhi  staff   510 27 Feb 15:08 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff   672 27 Feb 15:08 README.txt
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff   860 27 Feb 15:08 custom-logback.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff  2642 27 Feb 15:08 logging.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff  1434 27 Feb 15:08 neo4j-http-logging.xml
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff  3367 27 Feb 15:08 neo4j-server.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff  1484 27 Feb 15:08 neo4j-wrapper.conf
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff  1000 27 Feb 15:08 neo4j.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 doduibhi  staff  2653 27 Feb 15:08 windows-wrapper-logging.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps have a version conflict? You're speaking of Neo4j 1.9 but your log shows 1.8.2 do you by chance have the old version still installed as service?

Perhaps go to your Neo4j 1.8.2 installation and run bin/neo4j remove

And then please download the final release: Neo4j 1.9 (stable) from http://neo4j.org/download and try again.

To verify I just downloaded a new version of Neo4j 1.8.2 from neo4j.org on my Mac and it started instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Also,
please try the more up-to-date homebrew installation (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) with

```
brew install neo4j
neo4j start
```