# Can't get neo4j to start - conf/log4j.properties

Tags: neo4j

I've just used homebrew to successfully install the latest neo4j (Community Edition 2.1.4) on my MacBook Pro - however, I've been unable to get the server to start.

My question seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869173/startup-failure-for-neo4j-on-osx-10-7-5-re-log4j-properties) though that question remains unresolved (and the suggestions haven't worked for me).

Just quickly: I have previously successfully installed and booted the trial of the Enterprise Edition (over a year ago) and I've since removed it. Pure speculation but I'm guessing that my issues could be related to this.

When I run `neo4j start`

I get

```
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew -Djava.awt.headless=true
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [1368]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

Then I inspect with `neo4j console` and get

```
WARNING: Max 256 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=homebrew -Djava.awt.headless=true
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:conf/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: conf/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:459)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:471)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:125)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:243)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:121)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:conf/log4j.properties].
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils.locate(ConfigurationUtils.java:447)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.load(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:197)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:162)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:220)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:62)
```

It seems `conf/log4j.properties` isn't created at all.  I've then copied the contents of that file from my brothers successful installation which seems to remedy the first error though the second error persists with the same result when I try to start the server again.

I've also tried to install via direct download and get the same result.

Other details:

```
>> java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

>> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.4
BuildVersion:   13E28
```

I'm aware of the Max open files warning though don't believe that to be the issue.

Help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some success – or, at least, I've got neo4j working now on my machine.

Following the suggestion in [this google thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/red5interest/-RYScJWBOa4) I removed slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar from /Library/Java/Extensions and the server now boots.

I have no idea if this will have unexpected negative consequences but it definitely seems to solve my problem.  Moving on.